# Unable to manually create Lambda expression tree with List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression-trees

I need help creating this lambda expression manually. I cannot get past properly creating `MemberExpression` that isolates the "`Breed`" property of the underlying `List<Dog>`.  `Breed` is a property of `Dog` in this example.

*This is the lambda I need to create manually:*

```
int maxlen = dogList.Select(d => d.Breed.Trim().Length).OrderByDescending(d1 => d1).First();
```

Here is my attempt at trying to get the `Breed` property:

```
ParameterExpression dogParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<Dog>), "dog");

MemberExpression dogMember = 
    Expression.Field(dogParam, dogMember.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetProperty("Breed"));
```

Comment: Cheat: `Expression<Func<List<Dog>, int>> exp = dogList => dogList.Select(d => d.Breed.Trim().Length).OrderByDescending(d1 => d1).First()` and then take a look with the VS Debugger

Comment: The code under "This is the lambda I need to create manually:" is not a lambda expression. It's an `int` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *pain*, a real *pain*.

First notice that you can cheat, and take a look at what the compiler generates:

```
Expression<Func<List<Dog>, int>> exp = dogList => dogList.Select(d => d.Breed.Trim().Length).OrderByDescending(d1 => d1).First();
```

Sadly this isn't really a big help... You have two "inner" lambda expressions (the `Select` and the `OrderByDescending`) and three generic methods (`Select`, `OrderByDescending`, `First`)... A *pain*.

I've commented all the lines of code, so it should be pretty clear what everything does.

```
// The dogList parameter
ParameterExpression dogParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<Dog>), "dog");

// Begin of inner Select expression

// d parameter
ParameterExpression dParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dog), "d");

// d.Breed *property* access (if it is a *field*, use Expression.Field)
MemberExpression dogProperty = Expression.Property(dParam, nameof(Dog.Breed));

// d.Breed.Trim() method call
MethodCallExpression trimCall = Expression.Call(dogProperty, nameof(string.Trim), Type.EmptyTypes);

// d.Breed.Trim().Length property access
MemberExpression lengthProperty = Expression.Property(trimCall, nameof(string.Length));

// d => d.Breed.Trim().Length
Expression<Func<Dog, int>> selectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dog, int>>(lengthProperty, dParam);

// End of inner Select expression

// Find the "right" overload of Enumerable.Select... A pain.
MethodInfo selectTSourceTResult = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                    where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select)
                                    let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                    where args.Length == 2
                                    let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                    where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                        pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                        pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args[0], args[1])
                                    select x).Single();

// Make the generic overload of Enumerable.Select "specific" for using with Func<Dog, int>
MethodInfo selectDogInt32 = selectTSourceTResult.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Dog), typeof(int));

// Note that Enumerable.Select is a static method, the first parameter is the IEnumerable, the second is the Func<,>
// Enumerable.Select(dogList, d => d.Breed.Trim().Length)
MethodCallExpression selectCall = Expression.Call(selectDogInt32, dogParam, selectExpression);

// Begin of inner OrderByDescending expression

// d1 parameter
ParameterExpression d1Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "d1");

// d1 => d1
Expression<Func<int, int>> orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(d1Param, d1Param);

// End of inner OrderByDescending expression

// Find the "right" overload of Enumerable.OrderByDescending... Another pain.
MethodInfo orderByDescendingTSourceTKey = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                            where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.OrderByDescending)
                                            let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                            where args.Length == 2
                                            let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                            where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                                pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args[0], args[1])
                                            select x).Single();

// Make the generic overload of Enumerable.OrderByDescending "specific" for using with Func<int, int>
MethodInfo orderByDescendingInt32Int32 = orderByDescendingTSourceTKey.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int), typeof(int));

// Note that Enumerable.OrderByDescending is a static method, the first parameter is the IEnumerable, the second is the Func<,>
// Enumerable.OrderByDescending(Enumerable.Select(...), d1 => d1)
MethodCallExpression orderByDescendingCall = Expression.Call(orderByDescendingInt32Int32, selectCall, orderByExpression);

// Find the "right" overload of Enumerable.First... Third big pain.
MethodInfo firstTSource = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                            where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.First)
                            let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                            where args.Length == 1
                            let pars = x.GetParameters()
                            where pars.Length == 1 &&
                                pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0])
                            select x).Single();

// Make the generic overload of Enumerable.OrderByDescending "specific" for using with int
MethodInfo firstInt32 = firstTSource.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

// Note that Enumerable.First is a static method, the first parameter is the IEnumerable
// Enumerable.First(Enumerable.OrderByDescending(...))
MethodCallExpression firstCall = Expression.Call(firstInt32, orderByDescendingCall);
```

Comment: This looks very helpful. I will examine it closely but it looks like exactly what i need!

Comment: @ChiliYago If you need, I keep a gist with all the `MethodInfo` of .NET 5.0 (it is autogenerated, I have a script to do it): https://gist.github.com/xanatos/3a4c2f6658975a9e63893d305ae9ef67 . You can copy/paste the ones you need (like I did in the response)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your problem lies exactly, but it already helps to point you to the API that you'll most probably need:

You can use `Expression.Lambda` to create a lambda expression as the parameter for the `Select`. Within the lambda expression, you'll need `Expression.MakeMemberAccess` to access the `Breed` property. You'll need reflection methods (e.g. `Type.GetMember`) to get the relevant `MemberInfo` objects.